# Exception thrown while trying to deserialize a json-type string using gson

Tags: android, json, gson, deserialization, json-deserialization

I am trying to deserialise a `JSON` using `Gson`. Unfortunately, I keep getting this exception:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JsonObject

The line of code that throws this exception is the following:

```
completedIrrigations = gson.fromJson(json, type);
```

- "completedIrrigations" is an `ArrayList` of custom objects of type `ScheduledIrrigation`.
- "type" is initialised like this: `Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ScheduledIrrigation>>() {}.getType();`

This is the value of the string `JSON`:

```
[
   {
      "date":{
         "iChronology":{
            "iBase":{
               "iMinDaysInFirstWeek":4
            }
         },
         "iLocalMillis":1571961600000
      },
      "status":"accepted",
      "time":{
         "iChronology":{
            "iBase":{
               "iMinDaysInFirstWeek":4
            }
         },
         "iLocalMillis":56760000
      },
      "waterAmount":"27 mm"
   },
   {
      "date":{
         "iChronology":{
            "iBase":{
               "iMinDaysInFirstWeek":4
            }
         },
         "iLocalMillis":1572307200000
      },
      "status":"accepted",
      "time":{
         "iChronology":{
            "iBase":{
               "iMinDaysInFirstWeek":4
            }
         },
         "iLocalMillis":62520000
      },
      "waterAmount":"45 mm"
   }
]
```

Here is my model:

```
public class ScheduledIrrigation implements Comparable<ScheduledIrrigation>, Parcelable {

    LocalDate date;
    LocalTime time;
    String waterAmount;
    String status;

    public ScheduledIrrigation(LocalDate date, LocalTime time, String waterAmount, String status) {
        this.date = date;
        this.time = time;
        this.waterAmount = waterAmount;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public LocalDate getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public LocalTime getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public String getWaterAmount() {
        return waterAmount;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(ScheduledIrrigation o) {
        return this.getDate().compareTo(o.getDate());
    }

    protected ScheduledIrrigation(Parcel in) {
        date = (LocalDate) in.readValue(LocalDate.class.getClassLoader());
        time = (LocalTime) in.readValue(LocalTime.class.getClassLoader());
        waterAmount = in.readString();
        status = in.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeValue(date);
        dest.writeValue(time);
        dest.writeString(waterAmount);
        dest.writeString(status);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<ScheduledIrrigation> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ScheduledIrrigation>() {
        @Override
        public ScheduledIrrigation createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new ScheduledIrrigation(in);
        }

        @Override
        public ScheduledIrrigation[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ScheduledIrrigation[size];
        }
    };
}
```

**Note**:

As stated in one of the comments this code works perfectly when run on the android studio emulator(Nexus 5X API 28). Obviously I would like it to run on my device as well(HUAWEI CUN-L01 API 22).

Comment: It looks like `POJO` classes do not fit to `JSON` payload. Can you show your model?

Comment: @MichałZiober I've edited my question and added the model. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It looks like `time` and `date` fields look like `Joda Time`. I expect that you do not want to use `Joda` libraries in your app and just read `iLocalMillis` fields and somehow convert them to date and time, am I right? You expect `String` but date can be represented by many different formats.

Comment: I am indeed using Joda Time for dates and times. I am also using this library https://github.com/gkopff/gson-jodatime-serialisers that should help with the serialization and deserialization of custom objects that use joda time. I thought that by using this library I woudn't need to do the parsing myself. I will take a look around and see if I can achieve the same thing by just using the standard java libs for dates/times. @MichałZiober

Comment: The simplest solution would be to use `Joda`'s types instead of `String` for `date` and `time` fields. `LocalDate` and `LocalTime` I guess.

Comment: Yep, I figured and applied the changes. Now I get a different exception which is:

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JsonObject.

The line of code that throws it is the same one as before. @MichałZiober

Comment: It is hard to guess what is going on. Could you update question with new class and exception stacktrace? Do you have a problem with the same `JSON` payload?

Comment: I've just tried running the code on the android studio emulator (Nexus 5X API 28) and it works perfectly. Weird. I will try it out later on my phone and see what happens. Anyway, finding a solution is not urgent. It's just a matter of curiosity atm @MichalZiober